# Where to post questions requesting feedback not answers

Tags: discussion, support

I would like to get some feedback on a programming model I've come up with for a webapp I'm wanting to create.  This type of question is probably not constructive enough to be asked in the traditional way, is there a place to facilitate this type of discussion?

Answer (score 5):

If you have not yet written the code, Programmers is a better place than Code Review.  Questions on Code Review require already written and working code.